# R dplyr collapse rows and assign a label representing a range of integers

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a simplified representation of a transformation that I need to apply to a large complex table. Here, the input table is a lookup with two numeric columns. `raw` has a many-to-one relationship with `SS`. Many values of `raw` can have the same value of of `SS`, but not vice-versa.

```
library(tidyverse)
input <- tribble(
  ~raw, ~SS,
  0, 75,
  1,    78,
  2,    80,
  3,    83,
  4,    83,
  5,    83,
  6,    90,
  7,    93,
  8,    95,
  9,    98
)
```

The desired output table is below.

```
output <- tribble(
  ~SS, ~raw,
  100, '-',
  99, '-',
  98, '9',
  97, '-',
  96, '-',
  95, '8',
  94, '-',
  93, '7',
  92, '-',
  91, '-',
  90, '6',
  89, '-',
  88, '-',
  87, '-',
  86, '-',
  85, '-',
  84, '-',
  83, '3-5',
  82, '-',
  81, '-',
  80, '2',
  79, '-',
  78, '1',
  77, '-',
  76, '-',
  75, '0',
  74, '-',
  73, '-',
  72, '-',
  71, '-',
  70, '-'
)
```

To create this output, the input needs to be transformed in several ways:

1. Columns reordered
2. `SS` column has all missing integers filled in (70:100) and is sorted descending
3. `raw` column coerced to character, with three types of
   values to preserve many-to-one relationship of raw-SS:

   - a dash '-' for values of `SS` with no corresponding value of `raw` (e.g., SS = 70)
   - a single value (e.g., '2') for values of `SS` with a single corresponding value of `raw` (e.g., SS = 80)
   - a range of values
     (e.g., '3-5') for values of `SS` with multiple corresponding values of `raw` (e.g., SS = 83)

Here's how far I've gotten with it:

```
interim <- input %>% select(
  SS, raw
    ) %>% 
  mutate_at(
    vars(
      raw
      ), ~ as.character(.x)
    ) %>% 
  complete(
      SS = 70:100
      ) %>% 
  arrange(
      desc(
        SS
        )
      ) %>% 
  mutate_at(
    vars(
      raw
    ), ~ case_when(
      is.na(.x) ~ '-',
      TRUE ~ .x
    )
  )
```

If you run the above code, you'll see that the only remaining transformation  is to collapse the three `SS` = 83 rows into one, with a corresponding `raw` value of `'3-5'`. That means somehow recognizing that 3 and 5 are the lower and upper bounds of a range, because the solution will need to handle ranges of consecutive integers of indeterminate length.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `complete` and then do a `group_by` `paste`

```
library(tidyverse)
out1 <- input  %>% 
          complete(SS = 70:100, fill = list(raw = '-')) %>%      
          group_by(SS) %>% 
          summarise(raw = if(n() > 1) str_c(range(raw), collapse='-') else raw) %>% 
          arrange(desc(SS)) 
out1
# A tibble: 31 x 2
#      SS raw  
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1   100 -    
# 2    99 -    
# 3    98 9    
# 4    97 -    
# 5    96 -    
# 6    95 8    
# 7    94 -    
# 8    93 7    
# 9    92 -    
#10    91 -    
# … with 21 more rows
```

-checking with OP's 'output

```
identical(out1, output)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or use a `filter` step after `group_by` before the `paste`

```
input %>% 
  complete(SS = 70:100, fill = list(raw = '-')) %>% 
  group_by(SS) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1| n() > 1 & row_number()  %in% c(1, n())) %>% 
  summarise(raw = str_c(raw, collapse = '-')) %>%
  arrange(desc(SS))
```

Comment: Thanks to all for your help! I decided to implement akrun's first solution.

Comment: Update: akrun's first solution for some reason can handle double-digit integers as the max of the range, It omits them from the output table. Fortunately, his 3rd solution with the `filter` step can handle these cases.

Comment: akrun, I wonder if you could help me understand what the `filter(n() == 1| n() > 1 & row_number()  %in% c(1, n()))` is doing in this pipeline, particularly `n()` and `row_number()` - how are those functions used to filter in the rows needed for the next operation? Thanks!

Comment: @DSH The `n()==1` is checking for groups having only 1 row , or (`|`) if the number of rows are greater than 1 (`n() > 1`), get a logical condition to get the rows that are 1 and last row.  Otherwise, we can also do `filter(row_number() %in% c(1, n()))` It should automatically detect cases where with 1 row where both the 1 and n() are the same.  I used that to explicitly understand.  `n()` returns index of last rows, `row_number()` is the sequence of rows 1, 2, .. n() for that group

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, after this `filter` step, the data object has only 1-row groups and 2-row groups. The 2-row groups contain the first and last row of the input group, thus they contain the `min` and `max` values of `raw` for that value of `SS` (the grouping variable). Then the object is piped into `summarise`, where the `raw` values of the 2-row groups are combined into a single string with the `-` separator, and the 1-row groups are passed through with the `raw` value unchanged.

Comment: @DSH Yes, because `collapse` will collapse multiple elements to a single string.  If there is only one row, it remains as such

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way -

```
tibble(SS = 100:70) %>% 
  left_join(input, by = "SS") %>% 
  replace_na(list(raw = "-")) %>% 
  group_by(SS) %>% 
  summarize(raw = paste0(unique(range(raw)), collapse = "-")) %>% 
  arrange(desc(SS))

# A tibble: 31 x 2
      SS raw  
   <dbl> <chr>
 1   100 -    
 2    99 -    
 3    98 9    
 4    97 -    
 5    96 -    
 6    95 8    
 7    94 -    
 8    93 7    
 9    92 -    
10    91 -    
11    90 6    
12    89 -    
13    88 -    
14    87 -    
15    86 -    
16    85 -    
17    84 -    
18    83 3-5  
19    82 -    
20    81 -    
21    80 2    
22    79 -    
23    78 1    
24    77 -    
25    76 -    
26    75 0    
27    74 -    
28    73 -    
29    72 -    
30    71 -    
31    70 -
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` solution:

```
input_dt[, .(raw = ifelse(.N == 1, as.character(raw), paste(min(raw), max(raw), sep = '-'))), by = SS
         ][data.table(SS = 70:100), on = 'SS'
           ][is.na(raw), raw := '-'
             ][order(-SS)]
```

And `base`:

```
out_2 <- merge(data.frame(SS = 70:100)
               , aggregate(raw ~ SS
                           , data = input
                           , FUN = function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 1, as.character(x), paste(min(x), max(x), sep = '-')))
               , by = 'SS'
               , all.x = TRUE
)

out_2$raw <- ifelse(is.na(out_2$raw), '-', out_2$raw)
out_2[order(-out_2$SS), ]
```

Data:

```
library(tibble)
input <- tribble(
  ~raw, ~SS,
  0, 75,
  1,    78,
  2,    80,
  3,    83,
  4,    83,
  5,    83,
  6,    90,
  7,    93,
  8,    95,
  9,    98
)

library(data.table)

input_dt <- as.data.table(input)
```